# Complex Types support in Azure Search .Net SDK

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

I want to know whether complex types are supported in the azure search sdk for .net?

I already know that the azure team is providing a private preview of this feature. But the last information I have is that it can be accessed only directly via REST Api. Is there a .net sdk support for the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Complex Types is now generally available and is supported in [version 9 of the Azure Search .NET SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Search/9.0.0)

Comment: Thanks @Bruce for that prompt response. Eagerly waiting for that release.